# how don't permit to change text in html?

Tags: html, css

hi How can i prevent a user from changing text
I know that can be used 'readonly' and 'disabled' attributes
But it will be useless if the user has use the 'inspect element' in browser and text changed

please guide me
thanks

Comment: You pretty much can’t. Why would you want to do that?

Comment: The changes will only occur in the user browser..it would not go back to a server and affect that html page (unless you write some server  script to do that).

Comment: This is impossible, for several reasons.  What are you trying to do, specifically?

Comment: Draw the text onto a `<canvas>`? Websites that do this, I avoid. It doesn't scale smoothly with zooming.

Comment: i saved some data in a text box and i want to save it to database. and if user change the text box content, user data will save into db not mine

Comment: @HamidRezaYazdani Someone could just bypass the browser entirely.  You're going about this wrong.  You need to validate all that data server-side.

Comment: @Brad thanks. can i use of preg ex??? my data is static. like 'apple nokia samsung sony'. if possible guide me please.

Comment: @HamidRezaYazdani Listing some company names doesn't tell me anything about what you're trying to do.  Sounds like you have an enumeration of possible values.  If the list doesn't change too frequently, just set it as an ENUM in your database to ensure data integrity, and automatically fail if someone tries to put something else in.

Comment: @Brad i have a varchar(400) field in my db, then in my form some object select by user and i show them in a box as <span> and also save them into a hidden textbox. when i want save them, i read them of that hidden text box. i want user can't change value of text box

Comment: @HamidRezaYazdani What I'm telling you though is that you *can't* prevent the user from sending you different values.  It's completely impossible.  Instead, you need to enforce the list of possible values on the server, before you insert into your database, or by setting the appropriate constraints in the database.

Comment: @Brad i leave my code. how i define a preg ex for static values like 'parking - roomcount - master bedroom - phone'???

Comment: @HamidRezaYazdani Better to use an array of items and see if the selected item is in that array.  I don't know what you're using server-side, so it's not possible to provide you specific code.

Comment: @Brad i use $sql="INSERT INTO tblPosts ( features) VALUES ('$feat')" AND $feat=$_POST['fea']; AND fea is a collection of a product attributes.

Comment: @HamidRezaYazdani Well now you have another problem... none of your data is escaped.  Looks like PHP?  Use PDO or similar to enable prepared/parameterized queries to avoid this problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try the following code. This might Help You.

```js
$(function () {
    $('#sample').attr('readonly', 'true');
    $('#sample').css('background-color' , '#DEDEDE');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id='sample'>Hellow , This is a textarea without attribute readonly or disabled</textarea>
```

Comment: You're going to include jQuery and some JavaScript just to set attributes and CSS that you could have set in the HTML directly?

Comment: don't worked my friend. user can edit by using (inspect element) yet. try it yourself. thanks for your answer

Comment: @Brad i think he want to say onchange function. and when user change content, js code run